# Without calculating them determine whether $36^2+1$ and $154^2+1$ are prime and find the prime factors if not prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that $36^2 + 1$ is prime, $154^2 + 1$ is not, both are equal to $1 \bmod 4$. The prime divisors of $154^2 + 1$ should also be of the form $1 \bmod 4$. Tried showing this by Wilson's theorem however I don't feel like I'm getting any where.

Comment: What are you allowed to use, i.e., in which context was this exercise ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde +1 This level of detail is crucial for this type of problem.  You can't really answer a question with vague restrictions like "without calculating them".

Comment: Im afraid that was all the information that was given and is partly why i am so confused. The question was essentially a footnote after a corollary stating "All odd prime divisors of $n^2+1$ are congruent to 1mod4 and is within a chapter on legedre symbols and quadratic residues

Comment: @JakeClarke Thanks, knowing the context helps a lot, even if you don't think you have any details.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that they just want you to do trial division by primes $p = 5,13,17,\ldots$ up to $36$ (there are much fewer primes to try with the $1$ mod $4$ restriction).  For instance, to test whether $13$ divides $36^2+1$ you can compute
$$ 36^2 + 1 \equiv (-3)^2 + 1 = 10 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{13}.$$

For $154^2+1$ you might in the worst case have to go up to $154$ but actually you find a prime factor much sooner than this (below $40$).

Answer (score 1):

The square roots of $-1 \pmod 5$ are $2,3 \pmod 5$ but $154 \equiv 4 \pmod 5.$

The square roots of $-1 \pmod {13}$ are $5,8 \pmod {13}$ but $154 \equiv 11 \pmod {13}.$

The square roots of $-1 \pmod {17}$ are $4,13 \pmod {17}$ but $154 \equiv 1 \pmod {17}.$

The square roots of $-1 \pmod {29}$ are $12,17 \pmod {29}$ but $154 \equiv 9 \pmod {29}.$

The square roots of $-1 \pmod {37}$ are $6,31 \pmod {37}.$  $$154 \equiv 6 \pmod {37}.$$

Comment: Thus $$154^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {37}, 154^2+1=37 \times 641$$

Comment: $641$ , one of my favorite numbers. A divisor of $2^{32}+1.$